# Accessing an Element and Its Value in a List

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So say I have a list, List1 with lists in it.

```
list1 = [ [node1, w1], [node2, w2], [node3, w3]]
```

If node2 is present in list1, I want to get the value of w2. How do I do it in a quick way?

I couldn't find a relevant answer to the question while searching for it in stackoverflow. If there is one, I would be happy to refer to it. 
Thank you!

Comment: You DON'T do it in a quick way - lists support no way of finding elements other than testing them one at a time.  You want a dictionary here (assuming that node1, node2, etc. are values suitable as dictionary keys).

Comment: I couldn't use dictionary because I had to use the list as a heap and I don't know if you can use dictionary for that purpose. I was wondering if something could be done using '  if node2 in  list1' statement.

Comment: If you need to do a couple of lookups it may still be worthwhile to convert your list to a dict once you are done with the heap business. Provided your nodes are hashable it is as simple as `asdict = dict(list1)`.

Comment: I could, but the "heap business" is the main business. To be more precise I will be making changes to weight in every iteration and finding the node with minimum weight after the end of the iteration. So unless I convert the list to dict in every iteration, which I think will be very slow, I won't be able to practice the flexibility of dictionary here.

Comment: And I take it the heap structure is with reference to the weights so you can't use it for node lookup? Do the nodes change over time? Would it be possible to change the inner lists in-place? Then you could duplicate the nodes, use them as keys in a dict and store references to the inner lists as values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of doing what you are asking (using strings instead of your undefined variables):

```
list1 = [ ['node1', 'w1'], ['node2', 'w2'], ['node3', 'w3']]

for ix, l in enumerate([li for li in list1]):
    if 'node2' in l:
        print list1[ix][1]
```

If that data structure is not mandatory, a key/value pair structure would be much simpler (and faster! if you have lots of elements) to work with:

```
d = {'node1': 'w1',
     'node2': 'w2',
     'node3': 'w3'}

print d['node2']
#  prints w2
```

Comment: And to add, on checking for membership in a dictionary is faster than checking for membership in a list. So if you store it as a dictionary you could use `if 'node2' in my_dict: print my_dict['node2']`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple :

```
list1 = [ ['node1', 'w1'], ['node2', 'w2'], ['node3', 'w3'] ]
print([ l[1] for l in list1 if l[0] == 'node2' ][0])
```

Comment: Love the one liners, but i wonder if it's a concise for his usecase. Regardless +1

Comment: Thanks. But the conclusion I guess is we have to iterate one way or other if  we use list.

Comment: I'm afraid so.. How big is your list ?

Comment: @BinamrataSharma There are lots of data structures out there, are you sure you *need* to be using a list?

Comment: The reason I used list (and list in a list) is because I want to heapify the list. I thought only lists can act as heaps. Also, I used lists as element in the list instead of tuple because the items in tuples cannot be amended, right? I would love to learn about data structures that have the above mentioned properties.

Comment: @t.m.adam not really big. I could definitely use your code. I was just wondering if there are quicker methods out there. :)

Answer (score 0):

getting elements out of lists is relatively simple within python,
You just need to index into the list. this can be done to multiple levels ie:

```
example = [[1,2][2,4]]
print(example[1][1])
# will output 2
```

However in your specific case you could do:

```
list1 = [ ["node1", 1], ["node2", 2], ["node3", 3]]
for item in list1:
    if item[0] == "node2":
        print(item[1])

# this will print 2
```

You could always abstract this into a function and return instead of print for further use.

like this:

```
list1 = [ ["node1", 1], ["node2", 2], ["node3", 3]]

def ContainedInInnerList(ls, item):
    for x in ls:
        if x[0] == item:
            return(x[1])
    return None

print(ContainedInInnerList(list1, "node2"))
#output: 2
```

It would also be nice to use more complicated list comprehensions, to read about those go here: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk
I hope this helped.